# Likelihood Ratio Test for Equality of two proportions

Tags: binomial-distribution, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

Suppose we have two i.i.d samples from $X_1,...,X_n$ and $Y_1,...,Y_n$ where
\begin{align*}
X_1,...,X_n &\sim B(n,p_0)\\
Y_1,...,Y_n &\sim B(n,p_1).
\end{align*}

I want to show that we get the familiar test of equality of two proportions using the formal LRT.
\begin{align*}
H_0&:p_0= p_1\\
H_1&:p_0 \neq p_1.
\end{align*}

$$\Lambda(x) \propto \frac{\hat{p}^{\sum x_i + \sum y_i} (1-\hat{p})^{2n - (\sum x_i + \sum y_i) }}{\hat{p}_0^{\sum x_i}\hat{p}_1^ {\sum y_i} (1-\hat{p}_0)^{n-\sum x_i}(1-\hat{p}_1)^{n-\sum y_i}}$$
where
\begin{align*}
\hat{p} &= \frac{\sum x_i + \sum y_i}{2n}\\
\hat{p_0} &= \bar{x}\\
\hat{p_1} &= \bar{y},
\end{align*}

so that

$$-2 \ln\!\big(\Lambda(x)\big) \propto -\left[\sum x_i + \sum y_i\right]\ln(\hat{p}) - \left[2n - \left(\sum x_i + \sum y_i\right)\right]\ln(1-\hat{p})+ $$

$$\left[\sum x_i\right] \ln(\hat{p_0})+ \left[\sum y_i\right] \ln(\hat{p_1})+\left(n-\sum x_i\right) \ln(1-\hat{p_0})+ \left(n-\sum y_i\right)\ln(1-\hat{p_1}).$$

But I am stuck here? Can we take a Taylor series expansion of $\ln(p)?$ Around what point? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just to improve readability I suggest to use $k_0 := \sum{x_i}, k_1 := \sum{y_i}$. (I will use them.)

Comment: Shouldn't your test statistics has to be the next?
$$\Lambda(x)\propto \frac{\binom{2n}{k_0 + k_1} \cdot \hat{p}^{k_0 + k_1} \cdot \left( 1 − \hat{p} \right)^{2n − \left( k_0 + k_1 \right)}}{\binom{n}{k_0} \cdot \binom{n}{k_1} \cdot \hat{p}_0^{k_0} \cdot \hat{p}_1^{k_1} \cdot \left( 1 − \hat{p}_0 \right)^{n − k_0} \cdot \left( 1 − \hat{p}_1 \right)^{n − k_1}}$$
And a suggestion: if you make the substitutions $\hat{p} = \frac{k_0 - k_1}{2n}, \hat{p}_0 = \frac{k_0}{n}, \hat{p}_1 = \frac{k_1}{n}$, maybe you can get somewhere.

Comment: But I think this is simply not equal to $\frac{\hat{p}_0 - \hat{p}_1}{\sqrt{\hat{p} \left( 1 - \hat{p} \right) \cdot \frac{2}{n}}}$